# How to apply [@@deriving show] to a type from module parameter of my functor?

Tags: ocaml, ppx

I have a functor that takes a `Set` type like:

```ml
module type MySet = functor (S : Set.S) -> sig
  val my_method : S.t -> S.elt -> S.elt list option
end

module MySet_Make : MySet = functor (S : Set.S) -> struct
  let my_method set el = Some [el]  (* whatever *)
end

module IntSet = Set.Make(Int)
module MyIntSet = MySet_Make(IntSet)
```

`S.elt` is the type of elements of the set

I want to apply `[@@deriving show]` (from https://github.com/ocaml-ppx/ppx_deriving#plugin-show) to `S.elt` within my functor somehow, so that in one of my methods I can rely on having a `show : S.elt -> string` function available.

I feel like it must be possible but I can't work out the right syntax.

Alternatively - if there's a way to specify in the signature that the Set type `S` was made having elements of a "showable" type.

e.g. I can define:

```ml
module type Showable = sig
  type t [@@deriving show]
end
```

...but I can't work out how to specify that as a type constraint to elements of `(S : Set.S)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after a couple of hours more fumbling around in the dark I found a recipe that does everything I wanted...

First we define a "showable" type, representing a module type that has had `[@@deriving show]` (from https://github.com/ocaml-ppx/ppx_deriving#plugin-show) applied to it:

```ml
module type Showable = sig
  type t
  val pp : Format.formatter -> t -> unit
  val show : t -> string
end
```

(I don't know if there's some way to get this directly from `ppx_deriving.show` without defining it manually?)

Then we re-define and extend the `Set` and `Set.OrderedType` (i.e. element) types to require that the elements are "showable":

```ml
module type OrderedShowable = sig
  include Set.OrderedType
  include Showable with type t := t
end

module ShowableSet = struct
  include Set
  module type S = sig
    include Set.S
  end
  module Make (Ord : OrderedShowable) = struct
    include Set.Make(Ord)
  end
end
```

I think with the original code in my question I had got confused and used some kind of higher-order functor syntax (?) ...I don't know how it seemed to work at all, but at some point I realised my `MySet_Make` was returning a functor rather than a module. So we'll fix that now and just use a normal functor.

The other thing we can fix is to make `MySet` a further extension of `ShowableSet` ... so `MySet_Make` will take the element type as a parameter instead of another Set type.  This makes the eventual code all simpler too:

```ml
module type MySet = sig
  include ShowableSet.S
  val my_method : t -> elt -> elt list option
  val show_el : elt -> string
end

module AdjacencySet_Make (El : OrderedShowable) : AdjacencySet
  with type elt = El.t
= struct
  include ShowableSet.Make(El)
  let my_method set el = Some [el]  (* whatever *)
  let show_el el = El.show el  (* we can use the "showable" elements! *)
end
```

Then we just need an `OrderedShowable` version of `Int` as the element type. `Int` is already ordered so we just have to extend it by deriving "show" and then we can make a concrete `MySet`:

```ml
module Int' = struct
  include Int
  type t = int [@@deriving show]
end

module MyIntSet = MySet_Make(Int')
```

And we can use it like:

```ml
# let myset = MyIntSet.of_list [3; 2; 8];;
# print_endline (MyIntSet.show_el 3);;
"3"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can construct new signatures that specify the exact function `show` you need:

```ml
module MySet_Make(S : sig
  include Set.S
  val show : elt -> string
end) = struct
  let my_method _set el =
    print_endline (S.show el);
    Some [el]
end
```

Then you can build the actual module instance by constructing the module with the needed function:

```ml
module IntSet = struct
  include Set.Make(Int)

  (* For other types, this function could be created by just using [@@deriving show] *)
  let show = string_of_int
end
module MyIntSet = MySet_Make(IntSet)
```

Comment: That's a pragmatic solution. I was hoping to find a way to constrain the allowable element type of `Set` - do you think it's possible?

Comment: @Anentropic this is the way  In ML languages, constraints are defined by existential types and their operations i.e. module signatures.